# String manipulation library

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

EDIT: Have included only the relevant code

I have to manipulate an input string that looks like this

```
create /foo
create /foo/bar
write /foo/bar "text"
create /foo/bar/baz
```

And I've created this program (you don't need to look at all of it)
and the problem I have is with the function `printAllFolders()` which is called in the `main()` and it is defined right under the `main()` function. The problem must be in that function. Is it correct to pass the string in the struct `path[]` giving the parameter 
`comando->path` ?

When I put that function in the main it does give me segmentation fault issue. The rest works just fine.

EDIT: just to be clear, the `printAllFolders()` does print all the strings in the path array, so I just need to pass the `path[255]` array, not the one with all two indexes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct _command {
    unsigned char command[10];
    unsigned char path[255][255];
    int pathLevels;
} command;

command* createCommandMul(unsigned char* str);
void printfAllFolders(unsigned char* stringhe, int lengthArray);


int main() {
    command* comando = (command*) malloc(sizeof(command));
    unsigned char* upPath = NULL;
    unsigned char* allPath = NULL;
    FILE* fp;
    unsigned char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("/Users/mattiarighetti/Downloads/semplice.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
            comando = createCommandMul(line);
            upPath = upperPath(comando);
            allPath = fullPath(comando);
            printfAllFolders(comando->path, comando->pathLevels);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    return 0;
}

void printfAllFolders(unsigned char* stringhe, int lengthArray) {
    unsigned char* stringa = stringhe;
    int length = lengthArray;
    if (length == 0) printf("Cartella %s", stringa[length]);
    for (int i = 0; i < length+1; i++) {
        printf("Cartella %d %s\t", i, stringa[i]);
    }
}

command* createCommandMul(unsigned char* str) {
    unsigned char* c = str;
    command* commandPointer = (command*) malloc(sizeof(command));
    int commandIndex = 0;
    int pathLevel = 0;
    int pathIndex = 0;
    /* Parte Comando */
    while(*c != ' ' && commandIndex<10) {
        commandPointer->command[commandIndex] = *c++;
        commandIndex++;
    }
    commandPointer->command[commandIndex] = '\0';
    while(*c == ' ') c++;
    while(*c == '/') c++; 
    /* Parte Path*/
    while(*c!='\0') {
        if (*c == '/') {
            commandPointer->path[pathLevel][pathIndex] = '\0';
            pathLevel++;
            pathIndex = 0;
            c++;
        } else {
            commandPointer->path[pathLevel][pathIndex] = *c++;
            pathIndex++;
        }
    }
    commandPointer->path[pathLevel][pathIndex] = '\0';
    commandPointer->pathLevels = pathLevel;
    return commandPointer;
}
```

Comment: Does the `lengthArray` parameter tell you how many strings are it the array or what the last valid element is? If the former then you are reading past the end of the array.  If the latter then the name of the parameter is misleading.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't be the reason for you segfault, but it looks like you're leaking all of the `command` objects that you allocate.

Comment: I've made a bit of a mess in the code so, if It reads a command like `create /foo/dir` the `lengthArray` param does tell you that there are 2 strings in the array, and they are `foo` and `dir` @MichaelBurr

Comment: What do you mean by leaking? @MichaelBurr

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see in what place and what case the error happens to isolate and minimize the reproduction case? There are at least two lines of code which access memory outside array bounds.

Comment: If I delete the `printAllFolder()` function and print every string that is in the `comando->path[i]` array with a `for` it does output everything correctly. I think that passing `comando->path` doesn't actually pass the array `path[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is some confusion about the difference between an array:

```
path[255][255]
```

and a pointer

```
unsigned char* stringhe
```

When passing the array -as- a pointer:

```
printfAllFolders(comando->path, ...
```

the printfAllFolders() function sees stringhe as a memory address where there happens to be an unsigned char stored.  The printAllFolders() function does not know that stringhe actually points to a more complex object (array of unsigned char with [255][255] dimensions).

One fix to the question code is to change:

```
    void printfAllFolders(unsigned char* stringhe, int lengthArray)
```

to the following:

```
void printfAllFolders(unsigned char stringhe[255][255], int lengthArray)
```

This passes additional information to the function needed to understand the more complex nature of stringhe.

Of course, the following line (again) removes this needed information:

```
   unsigned char* stringa = stringhe;
```

Perhaps this line ^above^ should be eliminated?

Then change the line:

```
if (length == 0) printf("Cartella %s", stringa[length]);
```

to:

```
if (length == 0) printf("Cartella %s", stringhe[length]);
```

and then change line:

```
        printf("Cartella %d %s\t", i, stringa[i]);
```

to:

```
        printf("Cartella %d %s\t", i, stringhe[i]);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with pointers? Maybe a pointer to pointer?

Comment: Aren't arrays passed as pointers in functions? So `comando->path` pointer should be `path[]` array?

Comment: (A1:) Yes, most likely.  However, you will most likely have to come up with ways for code to figure out what the is being pointed to (or pointed, pointed to).  In C language, a pointer is just a numeric address of a cell in contagious memory.  Supplying that address alone, with no context makes very difficult for the compiler to parse the memory content.

Comment: (A2):  Yes.  Arrays are often passed as pointers to functions.  For example, strings are just arrays of characters; but even with strings, there are conventions that allow a function to parse the pointer values.  That's why the last byte of a C-string must be '\0', so that the end of the string can be parsed.  Pascal, on the other hand, uses "length-preceeded" strings; where the first byte of the string indicates the length of the string.  These conventions allow a humble pointer to be passed, and memory parsed (by using a standard convention).

Comment: (A3): "So comando->path pointer should be path[] array?"  Or, perhaps path (in the command typedef) could be `char **path;`  Which might mean that it is a pointer to an array of paths, each path being a char array.  However, there would have to be code to allocate memory to path (array of pointers) ... (sizeof char * times the number of paths), as well as code to allocate memory to each path(string).  This is very common in C.